# ESRGAN Issue — "Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled"

Tags: python, pytorch

Need help! Trying to run a python script with a pre-trained model (ESRGAN), but every time I face this error message. What could be the problem?

Before that I've installed the following dependencies:

- pip install pytorch cuda
- pip install opencv-python glob2

[image]

Comment: The torch version in the output is in an Anaconda environment. You are not using the torch version you installed with pip

Comment: How can I fix that? I used the following command to install PyTorch: "conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch."

Comment: You literally wrote that you used pip to install PyTorch. Which was it?

Comment: My bad, didn't specify that I uninstalled it via pip then and reinstalled using the command I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by tweaking a code a bit, changing a device type from 'cuda' to 'cpu'.

```
device = torch.device('cpu')
```

Comment: So your solution is to not use the GPU? Do you even have a CUDA compatible GPU?

Comment: Yes, it's CUDA-compatible. CPU-mode works fine for my task, so no need to get deeper into this CUDA-related issue.